# How to get the Cumulative percentile value of each row in a Python time series

Tags: python, time-series, percentile

How do I get the cumulative percentile value?

```
Dates
1990-01-02    17.24
1990-01-03    18.19
1990-01-04    19.22
1990-01-05    20.11
1990-01-08    20.26
1990-01-09    22.20
1990-01-10    22.44
1990-01-11    20.05
1990-01-12    24.64
1990-01-15    26.34
1990-01-16    24.18
```

The percentile value of the 2nd row within 2 rows of data and the percentile value of the 3rd row within 3 rows of data and so forth?

Comment: The process you are looking for is called cumulative operation. But there is no such thing as cumulative percentile. Can you explain what are you trying to do here via example & why are you doing it, i.e. your endgame.

Comment: I want to find the Percentile value for the Nth row value among it's N series and subsequently the Percentile value of the N+1 among the same N+1 series. This series would then contain all the Percentile values of each  row only compared only to the previous rows . I am doing this to see how 'high' or 'low' each value was in the distribution of its own past. @Zeek

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df=pd.read_excel('filename.xlsx') #replace filename with name of your excel file

df['date']=pd.to_datetime(df['date']) #this doesn't affect your percentile calculation but you do it to leverage full power of pandas datetime functions

val_list=df.val.values
vals=[]
perc=[]

for r in range(len(val_list)):
    l=[x for x in val_list[0:r+1]]
    vals.append(l)

for value in vals:
    perc.append(np.percentile(value,50)) #change 50 to the percentile you want to calculate
df['percentile']=perc

print(df)
```

A few key points to note here:

1) I have done the calculation via importing your data as pandas DF. If you want to do it in a numpy array itself a few tweaks to the above code should do it. But, Pandas DF is an elegant way to look at tabular data in Python.

2) This might not be the most efficient way, but it gets the job done. So, use it carefully on very big datasets.

3) Study the comments mentioned in the code.

Hope this helps ! If it doesn't reply in the comments below I'll try to sort it out.

Comment: i'm importing the data via Pandas DF. You are right, it does take a few seconds or so on big datasets but that's alright. I tired using the scipy library instead. 

perc = lambda x: sc.percentileofscore(x,x[-1],kind='strict')
df['Percentile Values']= round(df_IV['PX_LAST'].expanding(1).apply(perc),2)

This seems to work. Thanks for your nudge in the right direction. @Zeek